# Overriding default functionalities of rails_admin gem throws exception before execution of callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-admin

We have defined **config/initializers/rails_admin_index_override.rb** & **config/initializers/rails_admin_edit_override.rb** to override default functionalities of rails_admin gem.

But following code in **rails_admin_edit_override.rb**:

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Edit < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        register_instance_option :member do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get, :put]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            if request.get? # EDIT
              respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render @action.template_name }
                format.js { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
              end
            elsif request.put? # UPDATE
              exclude_models = ['product', 'manufacturer', 'language_code', 'vip_influencer_video_note', 'video', 'celebrity', 'vertical']

              sanitize_params_for!( request.xhr? ? :modal : :update ) unless exclude_models.include?(params[:model_name])
              @object.assign_attributes(params[@abstract_model.param_key])
              @authorization_adapter && @authorization_adapter.attributes_for(:update, @abstract_model).each do |name, value|
                @object.send("#{name}=", value)
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

executes before execution of callbacks which format data in expected format resulting into following error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidValue (
message:
  Value of type String cannot be written to a field of type Array
summary:
  Tried to set a value of type String to a field of type Array
resolution:
  Verify if the value to be set correspond to field definition):
  
config/initializers/rails_admin_edit_override.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Edit>'
```

How can I cause callbacks to execute before overriding default behavior of rails_admin gem?

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code of that elsif code?

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba I have updated the question with asked code surrounding elsif, kindly let me know if that helps. Thank you

Comment: when you say callbacks do you mean filters in controllers?

Comment: no i don't mean filters in controllers, i mean callbacks like (before_validate, before_save) defined at model level